# Are there counterparty nodes that one can run to support the counterparty network?

Tags: counterparty

- Does counterparty have its own set of nodes to keep its service up?
- Is it pow or pos system? Or is this just a centralized service?
- What was the purpose of it burning bitcoins to generate their own counter party tokens when its somewhat centralized?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, the project runs a reference node.

The PoW comes from Bitcoin, but anyone can run a Counterparty node. I don't know if there's a name for it, but maybe it could be described as a community consensus approach. All Counterparty nodes can validate transactions embedded in the blockchain.

The purpose of burning BTC was to make it a non-scam token. Those who burned BTC committed to the project. Another way to put it is it's a project without "investors". Proof of Burn was rare then and in the flood of ICO scams, it's never applied these days.

Comment: Where is the link to run your own counter party node?

Comment: https://github.com/CounterpartyXCP/Documentation/blob/master/Installation/federated_node.md - this installs everything in one go, inside of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM. Be sure you have 150GB free (because this also installs Bitcoin  Core with addindex and txindex).